# Group_by and summarise to substract values from different rows conditional to other value

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a variable that would be the difference the values of a variable depending on the value of another variable. More precisely, trying to transform

```
        patID  time     value
1       10    start        50
2       10      end        60
3       11    start        20
4       11      end        35
```

into

```
        patID   diff
1       10        10
2       11        15
```

by substracting the end Value from the start Value for each patID.
This is what I've come up with so far:

```
df %>%
mutate(start=if_else(time=='start',value,0),
         end=if_else(time=='end',value,0)) 
  group_by(patID) %>%
  summarise(start=max(start), end=max(end)) 
  mutate(diff=end-start)
```

It works, but I feel it's bulky and I have a feeling I'm not grasping the full potential of group_by and summarise functions. I'd love to have a more concise way of doing this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this directly using the `diff()` function:

```
df %>% group_by(patID) %>% summarize(diff=diff(value))
```

Output:

```
  patID  diff
  <int> <int>
1    10    10
2    11    15
```

This assumes that each `patID` has two rows, a start row and and end row, and they are ordered in that fashion (start row first, end row second)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr::pivot_wider` if ever you have multiple factors on a specific variable.

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(patID) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = time, values_from = value) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(diff = start - end)
```

you can substitute `start` and `end` as the factors you want to subtract.

Comment: Enforcing good practices (such as having tidy(in this case, wide) data) is always a good thing. +1

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful. Yay good practices!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler one. Just notice that alphabetically `end` comes before `start` and sort them after grouping by `patID`.

```r
df1 <- '        patID  time     value
1       10    start        50
2       10      end        60
3       11    start        20
4       11      end        35'
df1 <- read.table(textConnection(df1), header = TRUE)

suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(dplyr)
)

df1 %>%
  group_by(patID) %>%
  arrange(desc(time)) %>%
  summarise(diff = diff(value))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   patID  diff
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1    10    10
#> 2    11    15
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>